# Node/Webpack/javascript es6 - Add a condition on a require inside Object.Assign()

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a module that sets the language by requiring the right index.{i18n}.js

The code below works fine for pathes (urls) with /fr/, /en/, /es/...

```
module.exports = function (locals) {
  var route = global.RoutesPages.routes.find(r => r.url == locals.path);
  const language = locals.path.split('/')[1]; 
  return Promise.resolve(    
      locals.template(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        {           
          title:        route.title,
          type:         route.type
        },

       require(`../../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`)

      )
    )
  )

};
```

So it requires for `example.com/fr/cool` the file `i18n-build/index.fr.js`, and it requires for `example.com/en/cool` the file `i18n-build/index.en.js`

The issue is I have a case where the url is example.com/global and so the require tells me it can't find the right file because it tries to require for `example.com/global/foo` the file `i18n-build/index.global.js` which is to be expected because I don't this file and don't want to. Indeed for users accessing example.com/global, I want to use the `i18n-build/index.en.js` with english as a "global" user default

I tried to use a condition inside the require but then the build fails:

```
module.exports = function (locals) {
  var route = global.RoutesPages.routes.find(r => r.url == locals.path);
  const language = locals.path.split('/')[1];
  function isCountry() {
    //detect if language in uri is "global", 
    //i.e not a specific country
    if (language !== "global" ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return Promise.resolve(    
      locals.template(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        { 
          title:        route.title,
          type:         route.type
        },

        require( isCountry ? `../i18n-build/index.${language}.js` : `../i18n-build/index.en.js` )        

      )
    )
  )

};
```

It seems to break what was working before when webpack is building the files for one  url with /fr/, I get the error:

```
Cannot find module '../i18n-build/index.fr.js'
```

And the whole build fails.

I think how I write it is incorrect but i don't know how to apply a condition which basically goes like this:

If (isCountry), require `../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`, else require `../i18n-build/index.en.js`

**EDIT**

After some comments asking me to test various requires here are the results on the build :

- `require(`../../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`)` => build works
- `require(`../../i18n-build/index.fr.js`)` => build works
- `require( isCountry ?`../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`:`../i18n-build/index.en.js`)` => build fails
- `require( isCountry ?`../i18n-build/index.fr.js`:`../i18n-build/index.en.js`)` => build fails
- `require( isCountry ?`../../i18n-build/index.fr.js`:`../../i18n-build/index.en.js`)` => build works!!
- `require( isCountry ?`../../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`:`../../i18n-build/index.en.js`)` => build fails

The last one really suggest the issue is about how to properly create a condition on a require because both files do exist, i am not even using a variable ($language) inside them

Comment: And if you try simply like this `require('../i18n-build/index.fr.js')` just to test it doesn't fail?

Comment: I'll test now but i think it will work. coming back in 5 min to update the question

Comment: just put the result which definitely point to an issue with implementing a conditional require.  check my EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change your **language** assignment line by this:

```
const language = locals.path.split('/')[1] == 'global' ? 'en' : locals.path.split('/')[1];
```

And then use the 1st code **require**.

```
require(`../../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the error must be a typo , try add a `../` more in your conditional :

```
require( isCountry ?`../../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`:`../../i18n-build/index.en.js`)
```

Comment: It's super weird. I will added your suggestions which only...partly worked

Comment: check the 2 latest tests on my EDIT

Comment: what's the console.log of `language`?